# How to allocate dynamic memory and reallocate after reallocate how we bring middle freed memory to one block memory

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation

Assume 10k heap

```
int *p1;
p1 = malloc(3*K);
```

Then, a further 4K is requested:

```
p2 = malloc(4*K);
```

3K of memory is now free.

Some time later, the first memory allocation, pointed to by p1, is de-allocated:

```
free(p1);
```

This leaves 6K of memory free in two 3K chunks. A further request for a 4K allocation is issued:

```
p1 = malloc(4*K);
```

This results in a failure – NULL is returned into p1 – because, even though 6K of memory is available, there is not a 4K contiguous block available

How can I merge the two 3K blocks to make a single one of 6K?

the following code giving segmentation error.

if I free 2 and 4 row that freed memory two blocks marge as one block how it possible

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int** allocate2D(int rows,int cols)
{
int **arr2D;
int i;
arr2D = (int**)malloc(rows*sizeof(int*));
for(i=0;i<rows;i++)
{
    arr2D[i] = (int*)malloc(cols*sizeof(int));
}
}
void deallocate2D(int** arr2D,int rows)
{
int i,a,b;
printf("Enter from which row you want to delete");
scanf("%d",&a);
printf("Enter till which row you want to delete");
scanf("%d",&b);
for(i=a;i<b;i++)
{
    free(arr2D[i]);
}

}
main( )
{
int i,j,k;
int **arr2D;
arr2D=allocate2D(5,5);
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
   for(j=0;j<5;j++)
      {
        scanf("%d" ,arr2D[i][j]);
      }
}
deallocate2D(arr2D,k);
}
```

Comment: I have seen this question before (few days ago). The answer was then: you can't.

Comment: From an applications point, you *can't* "merge" blocks, since you have no control over the allocator. If you want that capability you have to create your own allocator.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude   how can we create our own memory allocater?

Comment: @praneeth write some code to allocate and free memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't defragment the memory, In case if you wanna do it, you cab call me.

I have already experience this kind of situation, but I don't have the code now yet I am still confident that you cant do this as it is impossible

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this can be answered in general, except with "you can't" since there really is no way using the standard library's heap API to do this.

There are special-purpose allocators you can use instead of the standard library's, which might expose more functionality to support de-fragmentation of the heap.

Comment: my friend asks that how can we mearge freed blocks all together to own block

Comment: tell me what are the special type of allocators for de-fragmention

Comment: @praneeth That can only be done in general if the blocks are adjacent, of course, and I guess most shipping standard libraries do this. Recommending software is off-topic for this site, you need to do some searching on your own.